# Use jquery to add params to video code

Tags: jquery, video

I am trying to create a page where users paste their video code and hit the go button. When they do this I want my params to be appended to the params they paste. I cannot seem to figure out how to grab the existing value and add the params. This is inside an object tag. Any help is appreciated. Here's the code:

```
Enter code for video:<br />
    <textarea rows="15" cols="50" name="code" id="code"></textarea><br />
    <button id="go">Go</button><br /><br />
    <script>

    jQuery('#go').click(function() {
    $("#code").val(function( i, vals ) {
        var myParams = "<param name=\"includeAPI\" value=\"true\" />";
        var $codes = $(vals).find('param').appendTo(myParams);

        vals += $codes;
          return vals;
        });
      });

    </script>
```

This script just gives me the original paste plus [object Object] at the end.

Snip of video code

```
<object id="video" class="video_page">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<param name="width" value="480" />
<param name="height" value="270" />
<param name="playerID" value="1412222" />
<param name="playerKey" value="556555dw4ff4r" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following script will give you the desired result:

```
<script>

    jQuery('#go').click(function() {
    $("#code").val(function( i, vals ) { 
       var myParams = '<param name=\"includeAPI\" value=\"true\" />';
       vals = vals.substring(0,vals.indexOf('</object>'));
        vals += myParams + '\n</object>';
        return vals;
        });
      });

    </script>
```

Edit: variation to handle additional input:

```
<script>

    jQuery('#go').click(function() {
    $("#code").val(function( i, vals ) { 
       var myParams = '<param name=\"includeAPI\" value=\"true\" />';
       valend = vals.substring(vals.indexOf('</object>'));
       vals = vals.substring(0,vals.indexOf('</object>'));
        vals += myParams + valend;
        return vals;
        });
      });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works although it strips code that comes after the object which I didn't paste in the case of brevity. I'll look into how I can add it back.

Comment: Ah, yes, wasn't thinking you might have additional input ... this variation would handle that:

Answer (score 0):

Use .add()

http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate an object with a string in this line:

```
 vals += $codes;
```

All you need to get the value appended in the textarea is:

```
    jQuery('#go').click(function() {
        $("#code").val(function(i, vals) {
            var myParams = "\n<param name=\"includeAPI\" value=\"true\" />";
            vals += myParams;
            return vals;
        });
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nxQ7g/

EDIT: For browser to recognize new param in object you will likely have to replace the existing object with a new and revised one. Add to above code:

```
var object=$('<object>').attr({id: 'video', class:'video_page'}).html($("#code").val());

$('#video').replaceWith( object)
```

Comment: I was able to do the same, but I need to get the param to add inside the object tag where the other params are. This method places the param outside

Comment: that is not what your question implied.

Comment: added a revision to replace existng object

Comment: Through no failt of your own I am unable to apply this. Not sure what I'm doing wrong in the integration. Thanks for your time.

Comment: put your code into jsfiddle.net on top of the one I made and save a new version

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#video').append($('<param />').attr({'name':yourName, 'value':yourVal}));
```

will add a parameter to your video